# Did Tom ever catch Jerry?

Tags: tom-and-jerry

Tom and Jerry have been playing the Chase Game for a long time, but I never recall Tom actually *ending* it. I do recall Tom eating Jerry, but I can't recall any moment when Tom *successfully* ate Jerry. Jerry always got away from Tom, and he hardly ever caught Jerry. So the question is: did Tom ever successfully catch and eat Jerry?

---

Well, you may say that if Jerry got eaten, the show would end, but of course the writers and animators can bring him back (reincarnation, or Tom eats Jerry in a dream).

Comment: Technically, Jerry is swallowed and reaches Tom's stomach [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_and_Jerry:_Robin_Hood_and_His_Merry_Mouse), but I'm guessing it's not what you're after...

Comment: By the looks of things, Tom is only interested in eating Jerry. As far as his goals, any time Jerry was in his mouth seems like he ended it as his intentions were fulfilled. Jerry always escapes. There is one episode where tom gets skinned alive by the dog. I recall them sitting on his empty skin and implying Tom was killed, but I don't remember if they justify that by showing the normal cartoon exit of Tom with no fur wearing boxer shorts. In their world, I don't know if anything can die.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I remember, **no**.

The only death that happens in the cartoon is on the episode [Blue Cat Blues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Cat_Blues), where it is implied that both of them commit suicide at the end of the episode (it is not actually shown).

From [Controversial Cartoon Deaths:](http://www.trendhunter.com/trends/tom-jerry-suicide-episode-cartoon-features-depression-over-a-broken-heart)

> This is not the typical episode about Tom & Jerry. Tom falls madly in
>   love with another cat and showers his sweetie with all sorts of gifts
>   including jewelry and even a car -- but she doesn't seem to be
>   impressed with his meagre fortune. He even signs away his arm and a
>   leg for her, but alas, to no avail. When things go awry, he later
>   becomes an alcoholic. Why? Mr. Butch (Tom's rival) stole his love away
>   from him.
>
> The heartbroken Tom winds up in the gutter and sadly, Mr. Butch ends
>   up marrying Tom's only true love. Of course, all of this is narrated
>   by a 1950's deadpan voice, which adds to the eerie feeling of the
>   short clip.
>
> The episode ends off with Tom on the train tracks with a train
>   approaching... This is definitely not a pick-me-upper.

Comment: While it's the only one for Jerry, it's definitely not the only hinted at death for Tom: There's a second allusion at the end of the episode *The Two Mouseketeers* (decapitation) and I also remember Tom being dragged away at the end of *Dicky Moe*.

Comment: This was supposed to be for kids

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any deaths happen. And even "Blue Cat Blues" didn't have anyone dying because the show would have ended, and the next episode was "Barbecue Brawl". And of course, Tom has eaten Jerry successfully... well, successfully until he reached Tom's stomach, at which point he escaped. This happened in the episode "Belly Ache'n".

Answer (score 0):

Tom has  *caught*  Jerry several times.

In one episode, Tom has caught Jerry and has ate him, but it isn't possible that Jerry cannot find a way out. Tom also catches Jerry and hurts him with mild houseweapons. The question you should be asking is:

*Has Tom ever **killed** Jerry?*

All in all, Tom has caught Jerry several times.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See [Southbound Duckling](https://tomandjerry.fandom.com/wiki/Southbound_Duckling) (1955)